# What purpose does @param annotation does in symfony2 class file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In the symfony2 and doctrine 2. I have this

```
 /**
  * Find a user by its username.
  *
  * @param string  $username
  * @return UserInterface or null if user does not exist
  */
function findUserByUsername($username);
```

Now i want to know that does it solve nay purpose or does it do anything in database with those `@param` and `@return` annotation or they just for documentation

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does @param mean in a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979046/what-does-param-mean-in-a-class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@param` is explained in the phpDocumentor [docs](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html). It has nothing to do with Symfony2.

Answer (score 1):

The link is outdated.

Here is a link to a good address at this present moment.

https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/param.html

Below, the first lines of the explanation in any case...

> The @param tag is used to document a single argument of a function or method.
>
> With the @param tag it is possible to document the type and function of a single argument of a function or method. When provided it MUST contain a Type to indicate what is expected; the description on the other hand is OPTIONAL yet RECOMMENDED in case of complicated structures, such as associative arrays.

Comment: The link is now available here: https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/param.html